# How can I make my matrix multiplication function (python, from scratch/no modules) more concise/efficient?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I'm new to computer science, and making a function to multiply matrices without any modules was an exercise on an online course I'm going through. My current code works, but it feels extremely messy/unclear, and I'd like to improve it. I tried to use list comprehensions to make the code more pythonic, but it still feels like nesting for loops with more steps.

My current code (takes in two matrices, A and B, and then returns A*B):

```
def array_mult(A, B):
    B_col = [[b[i] for b in B] for i in range(len(B[0]))]
    return [[sum([row[i] * col[i] for i in range(len(row))]) for col in B_col] for row in A]
```

I don't think I should have transposed B as a first step; it just helped me think about the problem.

My apologies to anyone who knows what they're doing who had to read that.

Comment: _"but it still feels like nesting for loops"_ Because it is! A list comprehension is just syntactic sugar for a loop that `append()`s to a list. Sometimes using a list-comprehension makes code hard to understand, so if it's anything more than two nested loops I prefer a regular old `for`.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I can definitely see where you're coming from that past a certain point, regular 'for' loops might make it more readable. Thanks! I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: You'll get better responses posting this question on the [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)